# How to pass this by ref in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, reference, this

In a class (ClassA) of mine I want to create a related instance of another class (ClassB) providing it with a reference to the object who has initiated it's creation. So I've provided ClassB with a construcror taking a (ref ClassB parent) argument. But in ClassA I can't just call var child = new ClassB(ref this). How to implement this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish here. You do know that reference types in .NET are already implemented through pointers, right? `new ClassB(this)` passes a reference back to the current object to the constructor of `ClassB`. Why do you need the `ref`?

Comment: I don't think you really meant to pass `this` by ref. `foo(ref bar)` means `foo` can point `bar` to somewhere else. `this` is a constant that you can't change, and in most cases you just want to hold a value of it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `ref` keyword causes [Pass by Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) semantics - that is, **if *the variable* is re-assigned in the called function, it will re-assign *the variable* in the caller** as well.

Obviously, this only works if a *variable*<sup>2</sup> (which can be re-assigne to) is directly passed as the argument and will not work if an arbitrary expression is passed. In this case, `this` is not a variable, rather a special expression which cannot be re-assigned, and so cannot be used.

As such, this would work: (But please see other answers and keep reading as to why this is likely *not required* and/or just silly.)

```
var me = this;
var other = new ClassB(ref me);
```

However, Pass by `ref`erence *should not be confused with* [Pass by Object [Sharing]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing)<sup>1</sup> semantics. Pass by Object means that **if an object is passed, *that* object is passed**: the object is *not* copied/cloned/duplicated. **If *the object* is mutated then *the object* is mutated.** All [Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) have Pass by Object semantics in C# unless either `ref` or `out` are used. (The `class` keyword declares a new reference type, as in the case in the post).

On the other hand, [Value Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) (e.g. `struct`), including `int` and `Guid` and `KeyValuePair<K,V>`, have [Pass by Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) semantics - in this case a copy *is* made and thus, **if the value is modified, only the value struct (which is a copy) changes**.

Happy coding

---

<sup>1</sup> Underneath C#/.NET achieves Pass by Object by passing a *reference to an object* by Value. However, the rules above correctly describe the observable semantics and effects.

<sup>2</sup> Unlike C#, which only allows variables to be used with `ref`, VB.NET allows Properties to be used. The VB.NET compiler automatically creates a temporary variable and implicit reading/writing instructions of the property during compilation.

Answer (score 11):

`ref` refers to variable references, not object references.

If you just want to pass a reference to an object, the `ref` keyword isn't necessary. Objects are already reference types, so it's their references being passed by value. The objects themselves aren't copied.

So, you neither need the `ref` keyword in the constructor nor in the instantiation:

```
public ClassB(ClassA parent)
{
}
```

```
var child = new ClassB(this);
```

Comment: @Jacksonkr: Just seeing this now, thanks for the edit. You missed the question, but no worries, I took care of it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass by ref in this case.  If you are passing ClassB(this), it will be passed by reference and not by value anyway.
Any changes made to the classA instance passed into classB's constructor will be applied to class A as well.

Comment: No, it's passed by value, but the value that you're passing is a reference!

Comment: @LukeH - correct, that's what i was essentially trying to say :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the `this` pointer, which is something that the `ref` keyword allows.  Why can't you declare ClassB like this?

```
ClassA m_classA;
public ClassB(ClassA classA)
{
   m_classA = classA;
}
```

Comment: Won't anything be copied in this case? Will classB.classA point to the original ClassA instance?

Comment: yes, classB.m_classA will point to the original ClassA instance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the ref keyword? All the types are basically passed by reference, so if you have ClassB take ClassA as constructor argument, just pass new ClassB(this), no need to use ref.

Comment: You mean "All reference types".

Comment: *All* types are passed by value (unless you use the `ref` or `out` modifiers).

Comment: @LukeH - I don't understand your point - you mean to say that the pointer is passed by value beneath all?

Comment: Yes. Whether you're passing by value or by ref is orthogonal to whether you're passing a ref type or a value type.